# rails highcharts and groupdate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I watched the railscast on highcharts and almost completed setting up the chart to display user signups for a specific date range.

Highcharts accepts an array for the data field

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
```

The problem that I am having is with passing an array using the group date gem. When I do something like this

```
User.group_by_week(:created_at).count
# {
#   2013-04-16 00:00:00 UTC => 50,
#   2013-04-17 00:00:00 UTC => 100,
#   2013-04-18 00:00:00 UTC => 34
# }
```

it gives me the datetime and then => the count. I am not sure how to turn this into an array like [50, 100, 34]. The data field should only have count numbers and not include the date.

Answer (score 1):

looks like what I was trying to do is turn a hash to an array. The first part of the hash is the key which is the date and the second part is the value.

I ended up creating a hash like this

```
@user_signups = User.group_by_week(:created_at, last: 12).count
```

then to get the array like this

```
@user_signups.values
```